# Using a postcode sector map with a population attribute, create clusters of those sectors to have a total population within a defined range

Tags: qgis, clustering, population, grouping

I have a postcode sector map in QGIS and one of the attributes is 'population'. I am trying to create a map showing what postcode sectors would need to be clustered together in order to split the whole country up into groups of sectors so that each group had a total population within a specific minimum and maximum range. I don't really care about the postcodes that fall between the clusters, they can be treated as noise for the purpose of this part of my task. I would prefer the clusters to be blobs rather than worms of sectors joined together weaving across the map. I have tried all the different types of clustering I can find and various plugins but none do the job, or i don't understand them enough.  Can anyone suggest where I should be looking or what I should be trying to find? (not knowing the correct terminology isn't helping at this point either).
I've tried. K-Means, Density Based Clustering, Group-average agglomerative clustering and many others but none seem to be easily implementable in QGIS.